# GetX (Rx<Color>) Error when Widget setColor from main.dart

Tags: flutter, colors, flutter-getx

GetX: Color Model Error

I separate the Model and Controller classes.

model. dart:

```
import 'package:get/get. dart'; import 'package:flutter/material. dart';

class Model { var name = "agus".obs;   var color = Colors.red[700].obs; }
```

controller. dart:

```
import 'package:get/get. dart';
import '../models/models. dart';
class PersonController extends GetxController {
   var models = Models();
   void changeUpperCase() {
     models.name.value = "testing";
   }
}
```

main.dart:

```
var modelA = Get.put(OrangController());
body: Center(
   child: Obx(() => Text(
         "My name is ${modelA. models.name}",
         style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, color: modelA.models.color),
       ))),
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
 modelA. changeUpperCase();
})
```

In the VS Code IDE, I get an error at IDE:

> The argument type 'Rx<Color?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Color?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write this line :

```
 var color = Colors.red[700].obs;
```

This is not a just `Color`, it's an `Rx<Color>` observable that contains inside of it the `Color` value, it's equivalent to :

```
Rx<Color> color = Colors.red[700].obs;
```

So when you assign it directly to the `color` property like this:

```
// ...
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, color: modelA.models.color),
```

You're trying here to assign the whole`Rx<Color>` instead of only its `value` which is the `Color`, basically, you need to assign it like this:

```
// ...
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, color: modelA.models.color.value), // added .value here
```

Now the error should be gone and the code works normally.